# Passing data from one instance of a class to another instance of a class in C#

Tags: c#, static, non-static

I'm trying to pass data from one instance of a class to another instance of a class - i.e. call a method (non-static) belonging to one class from another.

For simplicity's sake I'll make up the code here, but the principle will still be the same.

Our first class will be called *class1* and our second *class2*. *Class1* will be trying to call a method within *class2* called *myMethod* which takes parameters: int *i*.

Here's the code:

```
namespace myNamespace
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            class2.myMethod(5);
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        private int myInt;
        public myMethod(int i)
        {
            myInt = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can see some obvious problems in the code. Firstly there isn't an instance of Class2 for Class1 to pass the data to... However due to the nature of my program this has to be how it's done. (Class2 runs a loop meaning **no code beyond it gets run**)

A possible fix to this would be to have myMethod being static but then there's the problem of passing data from the static method to a non-static variable.

I'm not well read on interfaces, could this be the best fix? I also thought I might be able to write data from *class1* into a file and then have *class2* read and remove the data from the file during it's loop... but this seems a bit tedious.

So how should I be passing the data / calling the method?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to pass an instance of Class2 into Class1's constructor.

Comment: _(Class2 runs a loop meaning no code beyond it gets run)_ this seems to be a crucial point in giving a correct answer. When this class instance enters the loop? And how do you expect some other part of your code work if no code beyond it runs? Multithreading? Could you explain better the usage of this second class?

Comment: So the second class runs openGL (Tao, GLUT) and within it the main loop is called (rendering on each frame). It isn't in a different thread... I feel that multithreading might be the next step for the program

Answer (score 3):

You can try to change your `Class1` constructor like this:

```
public Class1(Class2 c2)
{
    c2.myMethod(5);  
}
```

Then pass your `Class2` instance into your `Class1` constructor:

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
Class1 c1 = new Class1(c2);
```

Comment: But I have a problem in that I can't create Class2 before Class1... (Reason being it's an opengl program and Class2 contains a loop meaning, as far as I can tell, no code past starting the loop is run)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not well read on interfaces, could this be the best fix?

No, not at all, interfaces have nothing to do here.

> I also thought I might be able to write data from class1 into a file and then have class2 read and remove the data from the file during it's loop... but this seems a bit tedious.

Hmmm, not sure I understand.

> So how should I be passing the data / calling the method?

In OOP you have 2 possibilities to invoke a method:

1. If the method is not static, create an instance of the class and invoke the method on this instance
2. Make the method static and then you can invoke it directly without an instance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your requirement, but the simpliest way would be to pass the instance of `Class2` to the constructor of `Class1`:

```
public Class1(Class2 c2)
{
    c2.myMethod(5);  
}
```

Then you can call your classes as follow:

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
Class1 c1 = new Class1(c2);
```